# Default Lead Source (or any standard hidden field) on Web-to-Lead form

Tags: leads, web2lead, form

I have created a web to lead form in salesforce but I cannot seem to default standard fields such as Lead Source = 'Web'. This should be hidden from the user creating the form. I am using the below but does not seem to be working, any ideas?

```
<input type=hidden name=“LeadSource” value=“Web”>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="lead_source" name="lead_source" value="Web" />
```

The easiest way to figure it out is to add the field in the web-to-lead form creator and then find the name and id.

Comment: I have been trying variations of this (form code is hardcoded into a wordpress template, no plugins) and nothing seems to be successfully passing back into salesforce. Any ideas why this may be happening?